# Connecting a frontend application to backend microservices

Tags: java, spring-security, frontend, microservices, netflix-eureka

Is there a way of making the requests from the frontend to the backend endpoints dynamic with Eureka? Or how does it work?

I'm fairly new to the frontend side and wanted to build a small application to gain more experience.
At the moment I'm using Spring security for the login but using Thymeleaf for the frontend.
My goal was to have separate pages and not using thymeleaf for that matter. Is it possible?
Also, I'm using spring security for authentication + authorization. How would I make that connection? Just with a normal API?

Sorry for the amount of questions, but I really want to know more about this!

Comment: _In general_, in a Real Application you would have some sort of router/load balancer that serves as the external endpoint the clients connect to, and internally it would use some configuration mechanism (such as Eureka) to determine where to send requests.

Comment: I've seen some integrations of eureka with Zuul, which works as a JVM router and  load balancer. Take a look at it, it may help -- https://www.baeldung.com/zuul-load-balancing  It's  also a Netflix project, so they may fit well together

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- so might be easier for me to use Thymeleaf to send the frontend the pages?